# How to separate chain related strings in hash table?

Tags: java, data-structures

For example, if I had two strings

`s1 = "stack"`,
`s2 = "stacks"`,

how would I implement the program to allow the strings to be placed under the same bucket (in this case `s1` and `s2` would be under the same bucket)?

Does this implementation have to do with the hash function?

I am creating a puzzle solving program and the whole idea is to eliminate the need to search for "`stacks`" if I know that "`stack`" does not exist in the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a hash function that returns the same value (hashCode) for both "stack" and "stacks". `BTW this is not a good idea`. hashCode generation should not be based on what you want to be in a chain (i.e, linked list when collision occurs in the hash table). It should be such that it returns a unique value for each object being added and reduces collision.

Comment: It is a problem out of a data structures textbook. I agree that it is a bad implementation. But I cannot think of another way to put two strings into a bucket. If I use any other implementation then each index will have a different string.

Comment: And why do you want to put it into the same bucket?. Though this might improve performance in one scenario, it might screw your performance in another .

Comment: You are right. I looked at the problem again and realized that I originally misread it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This would be little tough since String is a final class you wont be able to extend and override it. Probably what you can do is create a wrapper class which will have your string to be searched as member variable. You can store this object in hash table. Now you can override equals and hashcode in this class to match chaining string.

```
public class MyString
{
    public String string;

    public boolean equals(Object s)
    {
          //your logic for comparing string

    }

    public int hashcode()
    {
       //generate hashcode that is same for two objects true by equals
    }
}
```

Even with this I am not sure you will be able to achieve. I would suggest to use Trie data structure, it will make your task much easy.